# Interpretation of QM references

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations

Could anyone give me some good references for studying interpretation of QM?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics and links therein.

Comment: "Is the Quantum State Real? An Extended Review of $\psi$-ontology Theorems" [arXiv:1409.1570](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1570)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112968/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386126/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thank you very much